# Collect SQL Parameter from Web Application dynamically

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

I am building reporting application for my office like this,

[image]

Like in above picture, when i run some sql query written like 
select * from [TABLENAME] where [COLUMNNAME]=:Value , my application should read query and prompt for user input if there is : in query . I have no idea how to do this. How to solve this issue ???

Note: I am using C# and Asp.net webform for front end development. There might be any number of Parameter in query, this ones is just example.

Comment: That certainly doesn't look like a web browser

Comment: double click the button to get server side click event, hopefully you added asp:button

Comment: yes it not web browser but, i need to do it in web application. I had seen this in one of windows application, but no idea how they did this

Comment: @bresleveloper , and How to read query and prompt for user input ? There can be any number of parameter in query, this ones is just a example

Comment: build a string according to the inputs, like if inputA has value add 'Name='+inpatA.Text ect.